# What is Debug Mode and how is it working in simple terms?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Hi I'm new to programming. So in Visual Studio, there is an option of running in debug mode. I only have a general idea that this mode will create some pdb files, present errors in the output and help to debug your program, but I am not sure that except for those error information, how can those pdb files be used? Or a more general question, except for using the error information the output gives, are there some other efficient ways to debug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set breakpoints at certain line of code you want to inspect during debugging and check the values of variables and such.  You can step through the code to see how they are executed and in which order.  Just a very quick information.  Try out yourself.

Comment: Yes, it is. :-). The debug features are very much the same for the IDEs